# terraform referencing new resources via tags values

Tags: terraform

struggling to get my head around this, below is my real world example but I guess the general question is:

how to take a group of objects being created in a template and reference the ID a particular object based on something like a name tag, for use in another resource?

real world example:

So I am dynamically creating bunch of subnets based on a list of subnet names provided as a list variable

```
variable "subnet_names" {
description = "subnet list"
default = ["subnet1","subnet2","dmz-a","dmz-b"]
}


resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
count = "${length(var.subnet_names)}"  
vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 6, count.index)}"
map_public_ip_on_launch = "false"
availability_zone ="${element(slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, 2), count.index)} "
tags = "${merge(var.common_tags, map("Name", "${var.domain_short_name}-${var.subnet_names[count.index]}"))}"
}
```

This works fine but I then want to say, attach NAT gateway to only certain subnets,  for the example lets say the dmz but I cant figure out how to refer a subnet_id for a particular subnet created above... im thinking there must be a way to build a map of the new subnets {subnet_ID : tags.name} and select one via lookup of the tags.name which would be corp-dmz-a as example

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat" {
allocation_id = "${aws_eip.nat_gw.id}"
subnet_id = ???????????????????????????
tags = "${merge(var.common_tags, map("Name", "${var.vpc_name_prefix}${var.domain_short_name}${var.region_short_name}-NAT" ))}"
depends_on = ["aws_internet_gateway.igw","aws_subnet.subnets"]
}
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this would be appreciated, i have been experimenting with few different methods but think i'm missing some fundamental understanding and maybe there is even simpler way with interpolation and other functions that i am missing

Answer (score 2):

Managed to come up a solution that seems to work, also seems to be a pretty handy technique to share so answering here myself

```
//define data pull for subnets with a depends on the resource for creating the subnets so there will be subnets present before data is calculated
data "aws_subnet" "dmz_for_nat" {
depends_on = ["aws_subnet.subnets"]
filter {
name   = "tag:Name"
values = ["${var.domain_short_name}-DMZ-B"]
}
}

//Then reference that data for the subnet ID
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat" {
allocation_id = "${aws_eip.nat_gw.id}"
subnet_id = "${data.aws_subnet.dmz_for_nat.id}"
tags = "${merge(var.common_tags, map("Name", "${var.vpc_name_prefix}${var.domain_short_name}${var.region_short_name}-NAT" ))}"
depends_on = ["aws_internet_gateway.igw","aws_subnet.subnets"]
}
```